# iOS 5 - add Splash/Launch view with storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios5, storyboard

i create project with storyboard base uitabbarcontroller,
i try to add splash view that will show until server request will finsih,
so i create a new view controller class called "SplashViewControler" with xib file
and i try to add as subview to windows object.
the SplashViewControler not show...

any ideas how to Implement splash view with storyboard ?
thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd add that SplashViewControler to your story board. Then, using the story board designer, make the SplashViewControler the initial scene by checking off the "Is Initial View Controller" property of your SplashViewControler. Then, create a segue from your SplashViewControler to whatever your next view controller is. Make sure you name that segue. Then, when your server process is complete, fire that segue manually:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSegueName" sender:self];
```

I may be wrong but I think the HIG talks about not doing splash screens this way. You also need to consider how you will handle a server timeout or error from the server...

Comment: HIG says to add a progress indicator or spinner. "If the data is slow-loading or complex, provide users with a signal that processing is continuing. If a table contains only complex data, it might be difficult to display anything useful right away. In these rare cases, it's important to avoid displaying empty rows, because this can imply that the application has stalled. Instead, the table should display a spinning activity indicator along with an informative label, such as “Loading...”, centered in the screen. This provides feedback to users, letting them know that processing is continuing."

Comment: Link: http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html